# How can I redirect to the same page (the user was trying to reach) after updating his info through Action Filter Attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have this for my filter:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    if (userIsLoggedIn)
    {
         filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction("UserInfoActionName", "UserInfoControllerName");
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
```

I want to redirect user to the place he was after submitting his info.

my controller:

```
    public JsonResult Submit(UserInfoViewModel vm)
    {     
        //update user
        return JsonSuccess("Email for the profile has been successfully updated.");
    }
```

Comment: a description of the workflow would probably be helpful here as I'm having a hard time following what you're asking. If I understand/guess correctly, you have an ajax method calling the `Submit` action which returns some json. that json could include `vm.UrlReferrer` and then on the client side you can redirect the user to whatever location is specified in `vm.UrlReferrer` when the call completes. If it's a form post and not ajax, then just have the `Submit` action return an `ActionResult` and use the vm property to get them where they need to go

Comment: Yes, I have an ajax method calling the Submit action which returns json. I think I need to retrieve UrlReferrer in client side, but I don't know how :/

Comment: well to start you need to send the url referrer back to the client,so at the most simple level: `return JsonSuccess(vm.UrlReferrer);` then in the success function of your ajax call, access the url referrer and issue a redirect. there are a ton of examples out there on how to do this. if you were to post your ajax function, im sure I could come up with a complete answer for you